# Installing/running wxpython on Winpython Spyder

Tags: python, wxpython, spyder

I run python using Winpython. I would like to use the GUI libraries from wxpython in my Spyder IDE. I tried the wxpython installer but for some reason the packages are not copied to the WinPython\python\Lib\site-packages folder. I also tried the build it "Winpython Control Panel" which is supposed to add new packages but dragging and dropping the installer file didn't really work.

How can I install wxpython so that I can use it from Winpython Spyder?

Comment: Did you check with the winpython dev's?

Comment: Did you enter `C:\ WinPython\python\Lib\site-packages` when the wxPython installer asked you where to install?

Comment: I just tried doing something like what @RobinDunn mentioned and it doesn't work. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to find a solution to my problem.

Winpython has the option to "register" the distribution, this will add associate file extensions, add icons, and importantly for my case, register WinPython as a standard Python distribution. When I registered my copy of Winpython, in the Advanced tab of the Winpython control panel , the wxPython installer was able to see Winpython in the Windows registry and copy all the files to the corresponding folders.

Now if I run: `import wx`, it works